# text gets longer when zoomed out

Tags: html, css

I have a div in which there is an image and text everything is working fine but when it is zoomed out the text gets longer and jumps out of the div  currently i am using `overflow-x:hidden;` to hide it but why does this happen? This is my code  http://jsfiddle.net/z19n1jjg/

```
<div id="test"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301"/>
<p>content</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#test{
border:1px solid black;
width:300px;
height:320px;
overflow-x:auto;
}

#test img{
float:left;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

Comment: in the fiddle, I don't see the text getting longer or moving out of the box.

Comment: @Peege151 did you zoom out to 33%?

Comment: It seems fine at 33%, although the border under the scrollbar disappears, is this what you are referring to?  The text stays contained.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Works fine on mobile and desktop Safari.

Comment: @Peege151 seeing the problem in google chrome Version 38.0.2125 and in firefox, in firefox it happens like at the first zoom out perhaps try removing the `overflow-x:auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pixels. They will change on different display sizes.

If you want to code relatively, use em's instead of pixels.

View updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z19n1jjg/1/

```
#test{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:18em;
    height:22em;
    padding:1em;
}

#test img{
    float:left;
    width:5em;
    height:5em;
    margin:0 .5em 0 .5em;
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Still having the same problem and i used `overflow:auto` not `overflow:hidden`

Comment: did you try overflow:scroll?

Comment: you could also try overflow-y scroll

Comment: yes actually i can hide it using `overflow:scroll` and `overflow:auto` but i want to know why it happens

Comment: it seems to be working but the border disappears at a certain zoom level